# Convert a json string to an object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to parse a json string which comes with ajax.
Here is my ajax string:

```
{ 
 "baslik" : "fff", 
 "sorular": [{
     "soru1" : "1",
     "soru2" : "2"
 }]
}
```

That is my convert try:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SoruKaydet(string form_taslak)
{

  var taslak = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(form_taslak);
}
```

It is not giving any error but I get 'taslak' as '{[, [, ]]}'..What should I do?

Comment: You are using incorrect type. First row in JSON can be represented as KeyValuePair<string, string>, but second is not.

Comment: use `json2csharp.com` to generate the strongly typed `C#` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>` because the first line is a `KeyValuePair` of strings, the second one is a `KeyValuePair` of string and Array of object that each one contains some KeyPairValue.
I suggest to use the following structure to serialize the json:

```
public class Sorular
{
    public string soru1 { get; set; }
    public string soru2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string baslik { get; set; }
    public List<Sorular> sorular { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you don't know how much object will be in Sorular object my suggestion is use a dynamic object for deserializing the object. Like this:

```
 dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);
 Console.WriteLine(o.sorular[0].soru2);
```

This snippet allows create a `dynamic object` and then display `soru2` in the first object of the `List`.
Or if you don't want use dynamic instead of use the `RootObject` to deserialize use this class:

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string baslik { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> sorular { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is there can be more elements in json array "sorular".. Something like soru1,soru2,soru3,soru4... Count changes everytime...

Comment: Yes, but list holds only first two elements(soru1 and soru2) since Sorular has 2 attributes. If soru3 also comes with ajax string, it won't be displayed.

Comment: Added deserilazation with dynamic and with `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>` now choose what you prefer, tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

You should create appropriate model for this. Something like this:

```
  class MyModel{
     string baslik{set;get}
     List<Dictionary<string,string>> sorular{set;get;}
}
```

Then pass it to the method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SoruKaydet(MyModel form_taslak)
{    
  //use form_taslak here
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your comment.